# Python - How to iterate through the master directory, load each file and directly append them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to iterate through the master directory with a specific list of week numbers. load each file and directly append them.

I am getting an error while running this part of the code. tried some of the existing solutions, none of them helped.

```
# determine what weeks to load into dataframes 


month = 1
weeks = []

for i in sched.index:
    if (month == sched.loc[i,'start_incl'].month) | (month == sched.loc[i,'end_excl'].month):
        weeks.append(sched.loc[i,'weeknum'])

# iterate through the master directory with those weeks and append to all_files.


all_files = []

spath = r'C:\\Users\\shakir\\Desktop\\FY21'
filename = (os.listdir(spath))

for f in filename.index:
    if (weeks == filename.loc[f, 'date']):
        all_files.append(filename.loc[f, 'date'])

print(all_files)
```

I am getting this error.

> File "C:/Users/shakir/Desktop/WIP/E-Comm Merged.py", line 35, in
>    for f in filename.index:
>            TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: Here filename is a list, iterate using "for f in filename:"

Comment: What is the type of the variable `sched`? It looks like it's supposed to be a Pandas dataframe. (It also looks like you are treating `filename` as if it were a Pandas datafame.)

Comment: @r3t40 I want to get data for a month based on the date specified in weeks. I want the output to pull all the data in the "filename" that is in between or match the "date in weeks" above. I'm new to coding, so I know just the basics for now.

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi I have tried that but doesn't work.

Comment: @jjramsey sched is Pandas dataframe consists of date and weeks numbers. While filename consists of two separate data file each week. So, I would like to iterate through each week's file and pull the data that matches the date in "weeks".

Answer (score 1):

Try using enumerate:

```py
for f, item in enumerate(filename):
    if (weeks == filename.loc[f+1, 'date']):
        all_files.append(filename.loc[f+1, 'date'])
```

Comment: `(os.listdir(spath))` is not a tuple. To get the kind of tuple you're probably thinking of, you'd have to write `(os.listdir(spath),)` instead.

Comment: Just using `enumerate` isn't enough, though. `filename` is a list of strings, and a list does not have a `loc` attribute.